# Orthogonality with complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, orthogonality

I have these 2 equations:
$$\begin{align}
(68-4i,44+12i,-38-2i)\mathbf x=0  \\
(-66i-18,-52i-10,42i+12)\mathbf x= 0
\end{align}$$

I need to find the span of vector $\mathbf x \in \Bbb C^3$. 
I'm supposed to find a vector which is orthogonal to both of the vectors above.

Answer (score 1):

To find a vector orthogonal to both the vectors, you can apply the vector cross product to the two vectors as follows

$$u\times v=\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbf{a} & \mathbf{b} & \mathbf{c}\\
\color{red}{68−4i} & \color{blue}{44+12i} & \color{green}{−38−2i} \\
\color{red}{−66i−18} & \color{blue}{−52i−10} & \color{green}{42i+12}\end{array} \right|\\=
\left|\begin{array}{cc}
\color{blue}{44+12i} & \color{green}{−38−2i} \\
\color{blue}{−52i−10} & \color{green}{42i+12}\end{array}\right|\mathbf{a}-
\left|\begin{array}{cc}
\color{red}{68−4i} & \color{green}{−38−2i} \\
\color{red}{−66i−18} & \color{green}{42i+12}\end{array}\right|\mathbf{b}
+\left|\begin{array}{cc}
\color{red}{68−4i} & \color{blue}{44+12i} \\
\color{red}{−66i−18} & \color{blue}{−52i−10}\end{array}\right|\mathbf{c}\\=(-252-4i,-432-264i,-888-376i)$$

Thus the span of vector $\mathbf{x}$ is $\color{blue}{k(-252-4i,-432-264i,-888-376i)}$, where $k$ is a complex scalar constant.

Comment: how do you not mix up i-direction vs i-imaginary unit?

Comment: I used lower case $i$ for the imaginary component, and bold $i$ for the direction. Probably should have used a different notation like a,b,c instead to avoid the confusion  - have edited accordingly.